# PHP file seek performance optimisations

Tags: php, performance, caching, fread, fseek

I am building a website where the basic premise is there are two files. index.php and file.txt.

File.txt has (currently) 10megs of data, this can potentially be up to 500mb. The idea of the site is, people go to index.php and then can seek to any position of the file. Another feature is they can read up to 10kb data from the point of seeking. So:

`index.php?pos=432` will get the byte at position 423 on the file.

`index.php?pos=555&len=5000` will get 5kb of the data from the file starting from position 555

Now, Imagine the site getting thousands of hits a day.

I currently use `fseek` and `fread` to serve the data. Is there any faster way of doing this? Or is my usage too low to consider advanced optimizations such as caching the results of each request or loading the file into memory and reading it from there?

Comment: It is at this stage that you should consider using a database w/ indexes.

Comment: The data from the file will not be manupilated in any way however. It literally just stores random series of numbers and letters. The application will retrieve arbitrary segments of data (up to 10kb) by request of a user. So someone may ask for 1000bytes from position 10, and 1000bytes from position 11. Although the results will be almost the same, they are different. How would your database implementation address that?

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of hits per day, that's like one every few seconds? That's definitely too low to need optimizing at this point, so just use fseek and fread if that's what's easiest for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. It will probably be no more then a few per second max. Well if its not worth worrying about optimisation, I suppose I will keep using fseek and fread. I just didnt want to end up creating a bottle neck on the harddrive

Comment: When users start visiting sites evenly? What if the most part of them will come during a couple of hours?

Comment: @Eugene, even if all users visit the site within one minute it doesn't matter as far as the disk is concerned. Even a consumer grade desktop system can handle about a hundred disk seeks per second, and if the file is accessed often the os will serve the requests from virtual memory without actually accessing the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If it is crucial for you to keep all data into a file, I would suggest you to split your file into a chunk of smaller files.

So for example you could make a decision, that a file size should not be more then 1 mb. It means that you have to split your `file.txt` file into 10 separate files: `file-1.txt`, `file-2.txt`, `file-3.txt` and so on...

When you will process a request, you will need to determine what file to pickup by division `pos` argument on file size and show appropriate amount of data. In this case `fseek` function will work faster, perhaps...

But anyway you have to stick with `fseek` and `fopen` functions.

Answer (score 0):

***edit***: now that I consider it, so long as you're using `fseek()` to go to a *byte* offset and then using `fread()` to get a a certain number of *bytes* it shouldn't be a problem. For some reason I read your question as serving X number of *lines* from a file which would be truly terrible.

---

The problem is you are absolutely *hammering* the disk with IO operations, and you're not just causing performance issues with this one file/script, you're causing performance issues with anything that needs that disk. Other users, the OS, etc. if you're on shared hosting I guarantee that one of the sysadmins is trying to figure out who you are so they can turn you off. [I would be]

You need to find a way to either:

1. Offload this to memory.
   Set up a daemon on the server that loads the file into memory and serves chunks on request.
2. Offload this to something more efficient, like mySQL.
   You're already serving the data in sequential chunks, eg: line 466 to 476, it will be much faster to retrieve the data from a table like:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE mydata (
     line INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     data VARCHAR(2048)
   ) PRIMARY KEY (line);
   ```

   by:

   ```
   SELECT data FROM mydata WHERE line BETWEEN 466 AND 476;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the file never changes, and is truly limited in maximum size, I would simply mount a [ramdisk](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/), and have a boot script which copies the file from permanent storage to RAM storage.

This probably requires hosting the site on linux if you aren't already.

This would allow you to guarantee that the file segments are served from memory, without relying on the OS filesystem cache.